# Weird noise when pedalling

Tags: road-bike, chain, crankset, noise, mechanical

I noticed a weird noise when pedalling. I had my road bike with me when traveling (airplane), and I just came back from a trip. I only had to take the wheels off when packing it. Once I assembled the wheels back on, and gave it a try, I noticed this noise.

https://youtube.com/shorts/lSeDDDIvn-I?feature=share

What could it be? I tried lubricating the chain but it made no difference.

Comment: Any chance you can put the bike somewhere stationary, move the cranks and locate the sound. Is it aways present?

Comment: @DoNuT I tried doing that, and yes it is present when I pedal. Spinning the wheels on their now doesn't make any sound, so it doesn't seem like wheel issue.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a dry-ish chain to me. There might be a secondary source of noise but I'd add some more lube while you're trying to diagnose it. That said, that looks like a press-fit BB of some sort, which would be an obvious avenue of investigation. If you press real hard on the forward pedal while holding both brakes, does it creak?

Comment: Have checked the front derailleur position? Is the chain rubbing on it's side?